# system notifications - iOS

Tags: ios, background-process

In android, there are system intents that an application can catch to get notified about certain events like a change in wifi connection or phone boot completed etc.

Is it possible to do the same on iOS. I mainly want my application to run in the background and to perform certain tasks whenever certain events occur. the events could include a change in network connection, installation of a new app on the device device boot completed etc..

Answer (score 0):

Read here if the background tasks u want to run fall under the allowed categories :- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

In a gist, the allowed tasks are :-

Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app

Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app

Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)

Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content

Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories